# Atiyah and MacDonald, Proposition 2.4

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module, $\mathfrak a \lhd R$ an ideal and $\phi:M\to M$ an $R$-linear map such that $\phi(M)\subseteq \mathfrak a M$. Then $\phi^n+a_1 \phi^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n=0$.
>   *(Atiyah/MacDonald, Proposition 2.4, page 21)*

The proof goes as follows:

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a set of generators of $M$, then each $\phi(x_i)\in\mathfrak a M$ can be written as $\phi(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j$ with some $a_{ij}\in\mathfrak a$, i.e. 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n(\delta_{ij}\phi-a_{ij})x_j=0$$

By multiplying on the left by the adjoint of the matrix $(\delta_{ij}\phi-a_{ij})$ it follows that $\det(\delta_{ij}\phi-a_{ij})$ annihilates each $x_i$, hence is the
zero endomorphism of $M$. Expanding out the determinant, we have an equation
of the required form.

---

I understand the first part, but after "by multiplying on the left by the adjoint" I am not really sure what is happening anymore. Would somebody be so kind and shed some light on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once you have:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n(\delta_{ij}\phi-a_{ij})x_j=0
$$
you can rewrite this as $(I\phi-A)X=0$, where $A=(a_{ij})$, $I=(\delta_{ij})$, and $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$. Since $\text{det}(I\phi-A)I=[\text{adj}(I\phi-A)](I\phi-A)$, multiplying by $\text{adj}(I\phi-A)$, whose entries are all in $\text{End}_R(M)$, gives:
$$
\text{det}(I\phi-A)x_1=\cdots=\text{det}(I\phi-A)x_n=0
$$
and $\text{det}(I\phi-A)=0\in\text{End}_R(M)$.

Comment: And $\det(I\phi−A)$ gives us the desired polynomial?

Comment: Yes, because $\text{det}(I\phi-A)$ is the characteristic polynomial evaluated at $\phi$, i.e. $\phi^n+a_1\phi^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n=0$.

Comment: Did the matrix take value in the ring of $A$-endomorphisms of $M$?

Comment: @Keith The matrices take values in the $R$-endomorphisms of $M$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the clarification! I should have said $R$ sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A subtlety: at this point the text only defines $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,M)$ as a module, so the multiplication $\phi^n$ isn't defined. But pointwise multiplication for modules is not defined for arbitrary modules, so $\phi^2(x) \neq \phi(x)\phi(x)$, since the expression on the RHS isn't defined in general. Instead, $\phi^2 = \phi \circ \phi$.

Comment: @WarrenMoore And the $a_i$ we get in the equation are different (but related to, they are just a linear combination of) the $a_{ij}$'s, right?

Comment: @WanderingMathematician Also, to define precisely these matrices we need to specify what ring of matrices we're using. I suppose these are matrices over $\mathrm{End}_A(M)$. We already have that $\phi$ is an endomorphism, we can see the $a_{ij}$ as endomorphisms defined by multiplying by $a_{ij}$, but when defining $X$, how can we see the $x_i$ as $A$-module endomorphisms? I guess we can see them as the endomorphism $m \mapsto m + x_i$ and then everything still makes sense?

Comment: @Anakhand First, notation, the ring was $R$ not $A$. I don't think that's an endomorphism, since $rm+x_i = x_i(rm) = r x_i(m) = r(m+x_i) = rm + rx_i$ for $r\in R$ and $m\in M$. In fact, $X$ isn't a vector of $A$-module endomorphisms. We're acting $I\phi-A$ on $X$, and $I\phi-A$ has entries in $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ so it suffices for $X$ to just have entries in $M$. It's not true matrix multiplication, but a group action.

After all at the end of the day, the point of $X$ is to show that $\det(I\phi - A) = 0$ in $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$, which we do by showing it's $0$ on a basis of $M$

Comment: @WanderingMathematician Yeah, I see now that multiplication with $X$ is group action, and we can still write adjoint * (original matrix * X) = (adjoint * original matrix) * X because algebraic manipulation works "just the same" (due to the compatibility of group product with action, etc).

Comment: @WanderingMathematician A further subtelty which I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#A_proof_using_matrices_of_endomorphisms): we must consider the matrices as having entries in the subring $R[\phi]$ of $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ (where scalars in $R$ are seen as the multiplication map), because the latter is not commutative, so we can't define the determinant, but the former is commutative.

Answer (score 7):

The "adjoint" here means "classical adjoint". For a matrix $A$, the classical adjoint is the matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $(-1)^{i+j} A_{ji}$, where $A_{ji}$ means the $j,i$ cofactor---the determinant of the matrix obtained by omitting row $j$ and column $i$. The point is that the product of the classical adjoint and $A$ is a diagonal matrix with $\mathrm{det}(A)$ on the diagonal.

Comment: Ah, I did only know it under the name Cramer adjoint.